# On MacOS setting zsh as shell using chsh does not change $SHELL

Tags: macos, zsh

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/zsh
```

The abover changes my default shell to ZSH, however even after starting a fresh session `$SHELL` is still set to `/usr/local/bin/fish`, my previous shell.

So if I do `exec $SHELL` it starts a fish shell not zsh.

I already looked in `/etc/passwd` but I do not see my username.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting the machine fixed it :/